# Reverse-engineering Google SVG code

Tags: svg, google-visualization

I'm looking at some Google charts to get a feel for how to write SVG code. There's something curious about the dots on the scatter plots (these are just coloured dots superimposed on a grid).

Every dot is drawn twice, once as a large (r=12) zero-stroke white circle, and once again as a small (r=3.5) circle in the required colour:

```
<circle cx="304.73" cy="61.50050223557585" r="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#ffffff"></circle>
...
<circle cx="304.73" cy="61.50050223557585" r="3.5" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#dc3912"></circle>
```

Any idea what the point of this? Removing the blank circles makes absolutely no (obvious) difference to the output. I've played around with moving a (combined) dot until it's on top of a grid line, or overlapping another dot, and changing the size of the blank circle, but I can't see that it does anything at all.

Thanks -

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's there to trigger events for the tool-tip. You only need to move your mouse near to (within 12 pixels) a point on the scatter plot for it to display that point's information.

Comment: Aaah - knew there had to be a reason. The tooltip does actually kick in at about that distance.

Comment: How do you write multi-line comments in this thing?!%&*! Just working through your mouseover tutorial :) The Google javascript is obfuscated, so there's not much to be learnt there. I can break on mouseovers in Chrome (not Firebug - it doesn't think there's any Javascript there), but the code is so obfuscated there's not much to see. I think I can duplicate everything in ECMAScript.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't work out how the mouseover worked in Google, but the extra circles seemed like a good way to make it less picky. I generally prefer doing everything in ECMAScript - it's much easier to see what's going on then.